# What is the difference between 'Project Valid users' and 'Readers' group at project level in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

What is the difference between 'Project Valid users' and 'Readers' group at project level in Azure DevOps? These two groups exist in all the project and as per the MS docs it seems like they both do the same job. I know I can see the permissions when I can click on the groups but again, I don't understand the purpose of the group when they both do the same thing. Did I miss something?